# Custom Linux kernel module to display year, date and time

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm experimenting with creating a custom linux kernel module. I want to display:

```
year-month-day hour:minute:second.
```

So far I've gotten hour:minute:second to work, but I can't get Year to work. I'm using "tm_year" from the linux/time.h header, but when I cat my module the Year isn't displaying correctly. It's just a long string of random numbers. Any help would be appreciated. I only have access to linux headers as the kernel needs to run in kernel space. The code is ugly, but I'm just experimenting right now:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/seq_file.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

static int hello_proc_show(struct seq_file *m, void *v) {

// seq_printf(m, "Hello proc!\n");

unsigned long get_time;
int sec, hr, min, tmp1,tmp2, tmp3;
struct timeval tv;
struct tm tv2;

do_gettimeofday(&tv);
get_time = tv.tv_sec;
sec = get_time % 60;
tmp1 = get_time / 60;
min = tmp1 % 60;
tmp2 = tmp1 / 60;
hr = (tmp2 % 24) - 4;
tmp3 = tv2.tm_year;

seq_printf(m, "time ::  %d:%d:%d\n",hr,min,sec);
seq_printf(m, "Year: %d\n", tmp3);




 return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's expected behavior because you haven't done anything with tv2 except declare it on the stack.

Comment: @Peter obviously it's expected, that's why i'm asking for guidance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works.  I just tried it.  You can use time_to_tm() to convert between values.  Note that if you want to be very precise, use the system timezone to know hours, minutes, and seconds locally.

Also, I printed to the system log instead of a proc entry.

```
    unsigned long get_time;
    int sec, hr, min, tmp1,tmp2, tmp3;
    struct timeval tv;
    struct tm tv2;

    do_gettimeofday(&tv);
    get_time = tv.tv_sec;
    sec = get_time % 60;
    tmp1 = get_time / 60;
    min = tmp1 % 60;
    tmp2 = tmp1 / 60;
    hr = (tmp2 % 24) - 4;
    time_to_tm(get_time, 0, &tv2);
    tmp3 = tv2.tm_year;

    printk(KERN_INFO "time ::  %d:%d:%d\n",hr,min,sec);
    /* Add years since 1900. */
    printk(KERN_INFO "Year: %d\n", tmp3 + 1900);
```

Comment: thanks a lot! i've got a dumb question tho. when using the tm struct there's ints that you can use like "tm_mon" and "tm_mday". "tm_mday" says "the day of the month, in the range 1 to 31". What "month" is it talking about? If i add an offset to it to get it to match today's day of the month is it going to stay accurate from month to month?

Comment: @GeorgeCostanza [Your question is not dumb].  The details are in the code.  Most kernel subsystems do not care about outside info like day of the year, etc.  They look at timestamps, etc.  Inspect code here to look at how structs and funcs are typically used in the kernel: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/ (it is searchable)

Comment: I'm trying to incorporate system timezone like you suggested but I'm running into some issues. I need to use gettimeofday with the timezone struct. I need to include sys/time.h to use gettimeofday but I keep getting a fatal error no such file or directory. There's no examples online so I'm pretty sure no one would ever waste their time doing what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @GeorgeCostanza The variable of interest is sys_tz, which is exported by time.c.  Also check out: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time/timeconv.c and http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/time.c

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used in my kernel module to get system time

```
    struct timeval now;
    struct tm tm_val;

    do_gettimeofday(&now);
    time_to_tm(now.tv_sec, 0, &tm_val);
    printk(KERN_INFO "%d/%d %02d:%02d:%02d Days since 1 Jan: %d\n", tm_val.tm_mon + 1,
                    1900 + tm_val.tm_year, tm_val.tm_hour, tm_val.tm_min,
                    tm_val.tm_sec, tm_val.tm_yday);
```